# How to create a generic class for email notification using sObject to call in multiple class in case of DML error

Tags: apex, email-alert, method

```
public with sharing class EmailNotification {
   /**
   * 
   * @param  List<SObject> record
   * @param  String errorMsg 
   */
   public sendEmailAlert(List<sObject> record, String errorMsg){

      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

      String[] toAddresses = new List<String>{
         UserInfo.getUserEmail()         
      };

      mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
      mail.setSubject( '' + Datetime.now().format() );

      String message = '' + '\n' ;
      message = message + '' + errorMessage;

      mail.setPlainTextBody(message);
      List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(
         new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{mail},
         false
      );

      for (Messaging.SendEmailResult lvresult : results) {
         if (lvresult.isSuccess() == false) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN,
                         'Erreur envoi email : ' +
                         lvresult.getErrors()[0].getMessage()
            );
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to call my method from other class, in a catch exception.. When DML fails, I want to receive a mail alert.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for including code, but there is no actual question in your post. Please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the Help Center - especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it states, _'...a question post should include 1) A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help). plus ... 3) and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.'_ Please edit your question to add info.

Comment: I would like to use "sendEmailAlert" method in different class using try-catch every time a DML statement is present. How can I re-built my class to accomplish that?

Comment: **Firstly**, please edit your question (on the bottom left of your question are the words "Share Edit Follow Flag" - click on "Edit") to add additional pertinent information, rather than adding in the comments where it might be overlooked.

Comment: **Secondly**, when you say, '...use "sendEmailAlert" method in a different class...' do you mean that you want to A) call this method from other classes, or B) move this method to another class? (Or something else?) And when you say, '..using try-catch every time a DML statement is present...' do you mean that you want to A) add `try...catch` to this method, or B) add `try...catch` to the other class?

Comment: I want to call my method from other class, in a catch exception.. When DML fails, I want to receive a mail alert.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications and the edits to your question. This is how I now understand it, please correct me if I am wrong: You have another class which does DML in a `try` block, when that fails you want to handle it in a `catch` block in that class, and inside that `catch` block you want to call the above method in order to send an email.

Comment: Thanks to you... Yes... I have fews apex class with DML statement, and in that other class, i want to implement a try-catch block..each time I have an exception I want to receive a mail. I write an EmailNotification class to use sObject, to make it generic for future use in any class.

Comment: After making other (now deleted) comments, then re-reading through all of this, I seem to have misunderstood one big point. Are you asking for help on A) how to write the `try...catch` of the other classes, or B) just how to use the above code after it is called from a `catch` block of another class? If the answer is A), you need to edit your question to include what you have tried but has failed in the `catch` block of other classes. If the answer is B), you need to at least edit your question to show how you are calling the above method - what arguments you are sending.

Comment: if DML fails, don't you want to rollback the transaction? in which case, you can't send emails. Better to publish Platform Events